# Deal with sudo/interactive input in StartProcess

Tags: interface

#### Deal with sudo/interactive input in StartProcess

---

There is a example in document page of StartProcess

```
command = "";
process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];
Pause[.1];
processString = ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer];

Column[{
  Pane[Dynamic[processString], 
    ImageSize -> {800, 400}, Scrollbars -> True, ScrollPosition -> {-1, -1}], 
  InputField[Dynamic[command], String], 
  Button["Go!", 
    WriteLine[process, command];
    Pause[.1];
    processString =processString <> ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer];]
}]
```

This is useful, but not enought by now.

How can I do a cmd which need typing password? for example sudo?

For example, one of my purpose is to use this to batch check my hbase, and I need switch to root with ssh, and ssh to the server.

`su root`, if I do this in the Terminal, I need to type the password

Anyone extented this example of StartProcess?

Comment: [You can pass the password to sudo on the command line.](http://superuser.com/q/67765/98841)